# Apache access log is reporting thousands of GET requests

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Some weeks ago was being overwhelmed with ddos attack

After some research i fixed the proxy misconfiguration and activated Mod_evasive for apache, the slowlyness was gone.

I'm still receiving some types of request like this one
`51.159.210.176 - - [01/Dec/2022:20:51:26 +0000] "GET http://chongzhi.jusunpay.com:8122/pay HTTP/1.1" 302 217`

Are they harmless to my server? Also there is a way to disable this specific log? Because the access_log file is getting close to 50GB

Comment: You could install logrotate. That would save disk space by compressing logs and deleting old logs. I rarely want to look at logs from more than a month ago, so there's no point in keeping them.

Comment: Alternatively, here's a question which explains how to disable logs for requests matching a certain regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205569/dont-log-certain-requests-in-apache-access-log